# Odoo model inherit issue

Tags: python, xml, inheritance, odoo, odoo-14

I'm developing a custom view that inherit from email marketing module and add some email's templates, I coundn't find how to modificate the original view the terminal got me this error:

```
2021-06-22 20:18:26,442 48472 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: Loading module eroom_email_templates (37/42) 
2021-06-22 20:18:26,513 48472 INFO odoo odoo.modules.registry: module eroom_email_templates: creating or updating database tables 
2021-06-22 20:18:26,570 48472 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading eroom_email_templates/views/load_templates.xml 
2021-06-22 20:18:26,573 48472 WARNING odoo odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset 
2021-06-22 20:18:26,621 48472 ERROR odoo odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
2021-06-22 20:18:26,621 48472 CRITICAL odoo odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `odoo`. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 492, in _tag_record
    model = env[rec_model]
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/api.py", line 473, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'ir.iu.view'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/service/server.py", line 1198, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 453, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 346, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 221, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 733, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 719, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/home/developer/crm/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 681, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, near\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /home/developer/crm/custom-addons/eroom_email_templates/views/load_templates.xml:4, near
<record model="ir.iu.view" id="mailing_mailing_form_email_templates">
            <field name="name">mailing.mailing.form.email.templates</field> <!-- field name -->
            <field name="model">mailing.mailing</field> <!-- the model where the field belongs to-->
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mass_mailing.view_mail_mass_mailing_form"/> <!-- the ref field -->
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='body_arch']" position="after"> <!-- add content's routes -->
                    <group>
                        <!--   email templates box -->
                        <field name="email_templates" widget="html_frame"/>
                    </group>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

my module.py content is:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class EmailTemplates(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'mailing.mailing'
   _description = 'extension of the email marketing add custom email templates '

   email_template = fields.Html(string="TEST-22")
```

And my xml content is:

```
<odoo>
    <data>
       <record model="ir.iu.view" id="mailing_mailing_form_email_templates">
            <field name="name">mailing.mailing.form.email.templates</field> <!-- field name -->
            <field name="model">mailing.mailing</field> <!-- the model where the field belongs to-->
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mass_mailing.view_mail_mass_mailing_form"/> <!-- the ref field -->
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='body_arch']" position='after'> <!-- add content's routes -->
                    <group>
                        <!--   email templates box -->
                        <field name="email_templates" widget="html_frame" />
                    </group>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Also I'm trying to add a widget to show my email's templates but I don't know how to define the paths of my templates, drafts, sending and sents emails to show in it or if I should use a custom widget for this, and I tried to create a new module to modificate it with my module butthis got me the same error

**thanks for your help**

Comment: replace model="ir.iu.view" with model="ir.ui.view" and then try.

Comment: It didn't work and I got the same error :c